# Knowledge One filter does not reset on new case

Tags: knowledge, articles, data-category

We have an issue where the Data Category filter that is used to filter articles when a case is saved is still being used the next time the user saves a new case and searches for an article.

Any way around this? Does not look like there is much access to the way this tool functions in setup.

Comment: You mean the filter does not reset?

Comment: That's correct it does not reset.

Comment: Does it reset when the page is refreshed?

Comment: I know of issues like this in console where javascript is used to set a refresh timer.

Comment: No it does not reset on page refresh either.

Comment: Your users don't click the reset button right?

Answer (score 0):

The data category filters on articles have to be reset by the user by clicking the reset button.

It's possible to replace the page with a visualforce page and use Apex to auto reset the filter. The Salesforce Knowledge Developer Guide shows a number of code samples to create custom filters:

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_knowledge_dev_guide.pdf